# I can be white, I can be pink. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am generally white, but I can also be pink.
>
> I am popular.
>
> You can't live without me, but I can kill you.
>
> I am usually bigger than you would use me.
>
> Sometimes you add elements to me, sometimes you add me to other
>   things, but usually, you do not use me by myself.
>
> I come from water, but not from any water.
>
> I am part of you.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Thank you and thank you for your edit.

Comment: Clever riddle this as your first

Comment: Good&Plenty  (not the black ones)

Comment: I really wanted to make "elephant" fit as an answer...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I like this one. The answer is probably

> Salt!

I am generally white, but I can also be pink.

> Regular salt is typically white, but Himalayan Rock Salt is pink.

I am popular.

> Lots of people put salt on their food.

You can't live without me, but I can kill you.

> I can't remember what the exact biological benefit of salt is, but if you eat too much of it you'll die.

I am usually bigger than you would use me.

> Salt blocks can be very large.

Sometimes you add elements to me, sometimes you add me to other things, but usually, you do not use me by myself.

> People don't typically eat salt by itself- and I guess if the question is referring to Sodium specifically, it's combined with Chloride to form table salt usually.

I come from water, but not from any water.

> Salt can be derived from salt water (with extreme difficulty) but not freshwater.

I am part of you.

> Salt is a part of all of us.

Comment: This is almost definitely the answer, well done!

Comment: This was easy, I guess. I will try harder next time! :) Great job!

Comment: @MariaDeleva not at all! This is better than most riddles I see, and I didn't manage to get it at all

Comment: I like it plain... (cc @MariaDeleva )

Comment: "With extreme difficulty"? Just dunk your jeans in the ocean and hang them to dry.

Comment: I was thinking more about desalination plants, but I suppose that's a viable method as well. I don't think I'd want to put pants-salt on my food, though :)

Comment: I think the "adding elements to me" part is referring to iodine.

Comment: @LeslieP., desalination plants are used to get water without salt, which is very different from getting salt out of saltwater (i.e. in the first case, you want to get all the salt out, in the latter, you want to get some of it). Getting salt out of saltwater is as "easy" as putting some saltwater in salt evaporation ponds (very shallow ponds) and waiting for the water to evaporate.

Comment: Also, the "add elements" may refer to salts which include herbs or spices.

Answer (score 6):

Bit of a stretch but its the only thing I can think of

> Periodic table

I am generally white, but I can also be pink.

> Periodic table can be colored but I suppose its usually just plain white

I am popular.

> Everyone knows about the periodic table

You can't live without me, but I can kill you.

> It contains vital elements that we need to survive (like oxygen) but also contains harmful ones (like mercury)

I am usually bigger than you would use me.

> Either we use smaller versions or we only use parts of it and don't really use the lower and rarer elements

Sometimes you add elements to me, sometimes you add me to other things, but usually, you do not use me by myself.

> We can add elements to it, and add elements to other things to form compounds, but we don't use the whole periodic table itself

I come from water, but not from any water.

> It starts with Hydrogen from H<sub>2</sub>O which is water

I am part of you.

> Our bodies are made up of many elements

Comment: Colored periodic tables are not pink; they are *colored* (different pinks, are you sure?), i.e. different color for each group (alkali metals, noble gases, alkaline earth metals, metalloids, non-metals, halogens, other metals, transition metals, lanthanides, actinides). There might also be "unclassified" elements, i.e. Ununseptium.

Comment: you mix up the periodic table, a picture/printout of the periodic table and the chemical elements, but +1 to try to find another answer